# Get coordinates on click from a mesh face in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

So here's what I am trying to do. I want to build a panorama like this:

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama.html

And when I click i want to get the mesh's face and coordinates on that face. Is this even possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36030448/1697459)** for my answer on a similar question